# Ruby Mail Gem. Send email body with monospace font style

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm using the Ruby Mail Gem to send emails from a couple of scripts that mainly takes the output of an application and send the output in the body of the email and as an attachment also.

The thing is that in the body, the default font is not fixed size or monospaced and the text shows garbled to see it correctly.

This is the configuration I use:

```
@mail = Mail.new do
  body File.read('log.txt')
end
@mail['from']  = 'from@account.com'
@mail[:to]     = 'to@account.tv'
@mail.subject  = "Casos automáticos: Resultado #{@date_string} - #{ARGV[0]} - #{ARGV[1]} - #{ARGV[2]}"
@mail.add_file 'log.txt'
@mail.deliver!
```

I just tried with this settings with no impact on the font of the body:

```
@mail.header['X-Custom-Header'] = '<body style="font: monospace">'
@mail.charset = 'UTF-8'
@mail.content_transfer_encoding = '8bit'
```